# what is conditional distribution function of Y given N = n, correlation coefficient of Y and N, and what is effect of lambda on mean of Y

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

Y is a random variable defined as the sum of N independent Bernoulli trials where the probability of every bernoulli trial equalling '1' is equal to p. The number of Bernoulli trials N is itself a random variable that behaves according to a Poisson distribution function with the parameter lambda.

for part 1)
for P(Y | N=n) am I right to assume that I should substitute in the poisson function into the 'N' of the binomially distributed variable Y?

Is this somehow related to the correlation coefficient?
Would the correlation coefficient be positive because after all Y is the sum of bernoulli trials thus as N=n increases Y increases?

What about the effect of lambda on E(X)?
Should i define lambda as n.p so that as lambda increases, N=n must increase as p is constant?

Comment: ... What is $X$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $Y$ is the *sum* of a series of $N$ Bernoulli($p$) random variables; each realising values in $\{0,1\}$, where $N$ is Poisson($\lambda$) Distributed.   This then counts the "successes" among $N$ iid Bernoulli trials.   Thus $Y$ is Binomially($N, p$) distributed conditional on $N$.

$$Y\mid N ~\sim~ \mathcal{Bin}(N,p) ~\iff ~\mathsf P(Y{=}y\mid N{=}n) ~=~\\ N~\sim~\mathcal{Pois}(\lambda) ~ \iff ~ \mathsf P(N{=}n)~=~$$
 <s>Can you now complete and continue?</s>

However, you were asked *not* to derive anything this way.

Instead, please use the Law of Iterated Expectation (sometimes called the Law of Total Expectation). $$\mathsf E(Y) = \mathsf E(\mathsf E(Y\mid N))$$

Use

$$Y\mid N ~\sim~ \mathcal{Bin}(N,p) ~\implies~ \mathsf E(Y\mid N) ~=~ \\ N~\sim~\mathcal{Pois}(\lambda) ~\implies~ \mathsf E(N) ~=~$$

**Now, can you now complete and continue?**

$\Box$

Comment: @batmansashimi  What *is* $X$?

Comment: my bad replace all the X with the Y. where all the x there refers to the random variable y

Comment: @batmansashimi Well, as we've established, $Y$ is distributed binomially when conditioned on $N$.  What you have looks *nothing* like a binomial distribution.

Comment: Eh, no, wait.... did you substitute $\mathsf P(N=n)$ for $n$ in $\binom{n}{x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$ ?  Why would you even...?  No; just leave it. $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y=y\mid N=n) ~=~& \binom{n}{y}p^y(1-p)^{n-y} \\  \mathsf P(N=n) ~=~& \dfrac{\lambda^n~\mathsf e^{-\lambda}}{n!} \\ \mathsf P(Y=y) ~=~& \sum_{n=y}^{\infty}~\mathsf P(Y=y\mid N=n)~\mathsf P(N=n)\end{align}$$But, as stated, you asked in the your question not to use this....

Comment: Oh right, hahah my bad. so as for the correlation coefficient, how would we find that out? would the explanation simply be r= >=0 because as N increases E(X|N=n) for that value of n increases?

Comment: Find $\mathsf E(Y)$ as outlined, then similarly find the rest of the terms to determine the correlation coefficient: $\rho$ :  $$\rho=\dfrac{\mathsf E(NY)-\mathsf E(N)~\mathsf E(Y)}{\sqrt{~\mathsf {Var}(Y)~\mathsf {Var}(N)~}}$$
PS: recall that the Law of Iterated Variance is: $~\mathsf {Var}(Y)~=~\mathsf {Var}\big(\mathsf E(Y\mid N)\big)+\mathsf E\big(\mathsf {Var}(Y\mid N)\big)$

Comment: Thanks a lot! would you be kind enough to show how to then use this to EXPLICITLY derive the marginal distribution of Y?